# what are all the functions that satisfying $f(\frac{x+a}{b})=f(\frac{f(x)+a}{b})$

Tags: functions

Given $f(\frac{x+a}{b})=f(\frac{f(x)+a}{b})$, $x$ is a real number, $a$ is an integer number  and $b$ is a natural number.

What are all the functions that satisfying this restriction?

I tried to put some numbers for $a,b$ but can't see how it helps me..

Thanks!

Comment: What is the domain and range of the function? R to R?

Comment: I guess this is true for every $x$ such that $f(x)=x$, i.e. it is true for every fixed points of $f$.

Comment: @7raiden7 - but is it just $f(x)=x$ and you can one show it? and thanks for your comment

Comment: If $f$ is constant this is always true. More strictly, if $f$ is injective then its argument on LHS and RHS must be equal, and that leads to my conclusion. So, every injective function with a fixed point satisfies your condition. If $f$ is neither injective nor constant, I guess this would be the trickiest case.

Answer (score 0):

Beside $f(x)=x$, you also have $f(x)=x+c$, when $c$ is a real number.
But i don't know how to prove it and probably there are more functions.

Comment: If $f(x) = x + c$, then we would have $$ \frac{x + a}{b} + c = \frac{x + c + a}{b} + c $$ which is only true if $c=0$.

Comment: It doesn't have to be continuous right?